# Loss does not show a trend

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am not sure as to why the loss that I get does not show a trend of it decreasing. It doesn't show any trend at all in fact.[image]

From what I can gather from searching for "How do I get the loss per epoch in sklearn" and going through a few questions and answers I found that getting the loss after the `predict()` function has finished executing and produced a prediction then use that prediction through a loss function to determine the loss.

So here is the function responsible for that.

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVR as Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as ABS

def train(kernel, lossFunction):
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    model = Model(kernel=kernel)
    model.fit(xTrain, yTrain.ravel())

    pred = model.predict(xTest)
    err = lossFunction(yTest, pred)
    
    return (err, pred, yTest)
```

Here I run the `train` function 300 times in a loop then append the loss of each iteration to `loss`.

```py
loss = []
epochs = []
for iteration in range(300):
    err, _, _ = train('rbf', ABS)
    loss.append(err)
    epochs.append(iteration)
```

The plot shown at the start of the question is done with these lines

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lossFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=loss, columns=["loss"])
epochFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=epochs, columns=["epochs"])

results =  pd.merge(lossFrame, epochFrame, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
results.sort_values('epochs', inplace=True)

loss = np.array(results['loss'])
epoch = np.array(results['epochs'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))
ax.plot(epoch, loss)
ax.set(xlabel="epoch", ylabel="loss (mean absolute error)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? In general, given any data that behaves randomly with respect to any model, you will get a loss that won't converge. Loss only converges when your model is finely tuned to "learn" the appropriate information to decrease the loss. This is not a guarantee by any means.

Comment: @BobbyOcean My question is if I did anything wrong when I collect the loss. Because the loss jumps up and down randomly. And the predictions are very off.